# Bootstrap well background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a background colour to my well and for some reason, it's not overwriting the bootstrap default. I don't want to overwrite the wells class, just this particular one.

Adding the code directly in the html as a style tag works, but I want to keep my css in the stylesheet.

Example working code:

```
<div class="well" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
```

**style.css**

```
/* Progress Bars - Well */

.well-progress-bars {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

**home.php**

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

...

<div class="well well-progress-bars">
```

**Update:**

Appears to have been a weird caching issue with my browser. My original code was working, I was just unable to see by refreshing for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.well.well-progress-bars {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr5ovLbx/ - my original code is working, seems to be some browser caching issue :( wasted time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.well {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

or

```
.well.well-progress-bars {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

***Make sure your link tag for external stylesheet is below the bootstrap stylsheet.***

Answer (score 0):

When you use `style=""` in inline CSS, then it just could be overwritten by `!important`. Try adding `!important` to your CSS codes. In your failed attempt there is no need to `.well`, but you should try this:

```
.well > .well-progress-bars {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to override the Bootstrap CSS by either

a) defining a rule as specific as Bootstrap but after it, or

b) simply by being more specific than it.

Also, `>` does not mean something that also has the class coming after that sign, it selects an immediate child of some selector.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
.well {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="well well-progress-bars">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Yeah :( my original code was working, it was a weird caching issue with my browser.

Comment: @Saidin Well then, post that in an answer and mark this question answered, so it doesn't end up in a limbo here. And also, you can use the disable cache option in the browser dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by browser caching issue.

Original code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr5ovLbx/1/

```
.well-progress-bars {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```